# Create navigation property without foreign key

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have two classes like so:

```
[Table("GameLevels", Schema = "ref")]
public class GameLevel
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double PointsMin { get; set; }
    public double PointsMax { get; set; }
}

[Table("GameProfiles", Schema = "usr")]
public class UserGameProfile 
{
    [Key]
    [ForeignKey("ApplicationUser")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public int GamesPlayed { get; set; }
    public double Points { get; set; }
    public int WinCount { get; set; }
    public int LossCount { get; set; }
    public int DrawCount { get; set; }
    public int ForfeitCount { get; set; }
    public int GameLevelId { get; set; }

    public virtual GameLevel Level { get; set; }

    public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
}
```

Entity framework builds this so that `UserGameProfile` has a foreign key pointing to `GameLevel`.  I guess this is because of the `GameLevelId` property.

Is there any way I can get this to generate the tables and navigation property without the foreign key?

I tried:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<UserGameProfile>().HasOptional<GameLevel>(x => x.Level).WithMany();
```

But then database fails to build. With this error:

One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:

> Project.Domain.Data.UserGameProfile_Level: : Multiplicity
>   conflicts with the referential constraint in Role
>   'UserGameProfile_Level_Target' in relationship
>   'UserGameProfile_Level'. Because all of the properties in the
>   Dependent Role are non-nullable, multiplicity of the Principal Role
>   must be '1'.

Basically what I want is a zero-or-one to zero-or-many relationship.

How do I keep levels independent but have the ability to add a level to a profile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't drop the foreign key completely, otherwise, how do you expect the two entities (i.e, tables) to be linked? What you can do instead is have a nullable FK, which will effectively make the relationship zero-or-one to many.

In your `GameLevel` class, add a navigation property as a collection of `UserGameProfile`:

```
public class GameLevel
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double PointsMin { get; set; }
    public double PointsMax { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<UserGameProfile> UserGameProfiles { get; set; }
}
```

Then in the `UserGameProfile` class, make the property `GameLevelId` nullable:

```
public class UserGameProfile 
{
    // ...
    // ...

    public int? GameLevelId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("GameLevelId")]
    public virtual GameLevel GameLevel { get; set; }
}
```

This should work without even having to use Fluent API.

Comment: This still creates a FK from profile to level so I am unable to create a profile that doesn't have a level.

Comment: Nope! Having a FK, doesn't necessarily prevent that (so long as the FK is nullable). You should be able to do just that. Please read the first sentence of my answer. Having a nullable field (FK, or not) means that this field can have a `null` value, which, in this case, means that the FK doesn't have to have a value (AKA, zero-or-one).

Comment: Yes but having a foreign key contraint means that the parent must exist.  How do you create the child without there being a parent?  I am getting error when trying to insert profile without a level that it is violating the FK contraint.

Comment: Again, having a nullable FK means that a "parent" does **Not** have to exist". Not having a FK, on the other hand, means that the two tables _have no relationships whatsoever_. If after you modified your code to reflect the changes I showed in my answer you still have that error, please edit your question and include the new code (including how you create and save the profile and any related Fluent API).